# error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

i want to get a cell's value in datagrid wpf and i achieve  this like 2,3 etc. then i want to compare an int value with this cell's value but i cannot get cell's value. how to get a cell's value ?  my code :

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.AddedItems[0]);
            if (row != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

                DataGridCell cell1 = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(2) as DataGridCell;
                DataGridCell cell2 = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(4) as DataGridCell;
                DataGridCell cell3 = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(6) as DataGridCell;

                SMBPModelDataContext db = new SMBPModelDataContext();
                StoreDistributionInformation psaRow = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as StoreDistributionInformation;

    if (psaRow.Day1 != Convert.ToInt32((cell1.Content)))
    {

    }
```

i take this error in header : `psaRow.Day1 != Convert.ToInt32((cell1.Content))`

thanks in advance

Comment: Set a breakpoint, evaluate the values and figure out what's going on. Shouldn't be hard at all.

Comment: i tried breakpoint..i know it is not hard..at breakpoint, it drops to this error

Comment: I guess its because the cell Content is a TextBlock not a string, you will have to cast Content as TextBlock and get the Text property, e,g. `Convert.ToInt32((cell1.Content as TextBlock).Text)`, but I suggest adding some extra null checks/error handling around that